# Are isometric normed linear spaces isomorphic?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I should know the answer to this (and I did some time ago, but have forgotten): If the normed linear spaces $X$ and $Y$ are isometric (there is a bijective map from $X$ to $Y$ that preserves distances), are they linearly isomorphic (there is a continuous linear bijection from $X$ to $Y$ with a continuous inverse)?

Comment: How is Mazur-Ulam Theorem applied to the complex space? is it that the distance preserving surjective map with 0 to 0 on comlex spaces is real linear? Please show the proof.

Comment: You simply forget that you can multiply vectors by complex numbers, but still remember that you can multiply by reals. Now you have a real vector space, to which the Mazur-Ulam theorem applies. And yes, the conclusion is that the map is real linear.

Comment: I think the conclusion is   "If the normed linear spaces $X$ and $Y$ are isometric, they linearly isomorphic (i.e. they are isometrically isomorphic.)"  Is it not?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is true for *real* vector spaces by the [Mazur-Ulam theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur-Ulam_theorem) which states that a surjective distance-preserving linear map of one real normed space onto another is an affine map. Indeed, if $f: X \to Y$ is such a map then $g(x) = f(x) - f(0)$ is a linear and onto isometry. The inverse of $g$ is of course linear and isometry, too, so in particular, $X$ and $Y$ are linearly isomorphic.

For a proof of this, one can't do better than refer to [Väisälä's recent note](http://www.helsinki.fi/~jvaisala/mazurulam.pdf) which appeared in the Monthly, [see here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3647749) for the paywalled published version. References to the original works are given there.

Further remarks:

1. One corollary of the Mazur-Ulam theorem is that the group of isometric and onto self-maps of a real normed space is isomorphic to $O(X) \ltimes X$, where $O(X)$ denotes the group of linear isometries and acts on $X$ in the obvious way. This generalizes the usual description of Euclidean isometry group $O(n) \ltimes \mathbb{R}^n$ nicely.
2. If surjectivity of $f$ is dropped, the conclusion that $f$ needs to be affine is wrong. The example given by Väisälä is mentioned also [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59374/example-of-a-non-linear-isometry) here: if we equip $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the max-norm and take $\phi:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be a non-linear $1$-Lipschitz map then the map $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x) = (x,\phi(x))$ is isometric but not affine.
3. Isomorphic Banach spaces need not be isometric, as you showed yourself [in this recent thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80727/).
4. As far as I know, the case of complex Banach spaces doesn't have such a nice formulation, since we need to ensure complex linearity in order to avoid silly counterexamples that stem from complex conjugation.
5. Finally, the Mazur-Ulam theorem was mentioned in [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62380/), where Bill Johnson mentions a nice generalization by Figiel which shows in some sense that the counterexample given in 2. is worst possible.
6. Tangentially relevant is also [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80567) on notions of isomorphisms of Banach spaces.

Comment: I think you should delete "linear" from the first sentence.