# Isomorphic in the vector and norm sense

Tags: proof-verification, terminology, banach-spaces, isometry

If a Banach space is

> *isomorphic in the vector and norm sense*

to another Banach space, does this imply the two are *isometrically isomorphic*?

**I think so, because:** from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space)

- "*an isometry [...] is a linear map f which preserves the norm*"
- "*a surjective isometry [...] is called an isometric isomorphism*"

and Definition 1.3 from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Definition_and_Examples_of_Isomorphisms)

- an isomorphism between two vector spaces is a map that is one-to-one and onto and preserves structure.

So if two Banach spaces are isomorphic in both the vector sense and the norm sense, they must be isometrically isomorphic?

Comment: Isomorphic in the norm sense? Does it mean homeomorphic? Or that there is a norm preserving bijection (not necessarly linear)?

Comment: @freakish, I don't know. This is precisely my question, how to interpret the clause "*isomorphic in the vector and norm sense*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the two Banach spaces in question.

Isomorphic in the vector sense means that there exists a linear bijection $\Phi : X \to Y$. Notice that $\Phi^{-1}$ is also a linear bijection.

Isomorphic in the norm sense could mean several things:

1. There exists a bijective linear isometry $T : X \to Y$, meaning that $T$ is norm preserving: $$\|Tx\|_{Y} = \|x\|_X, \quad\forall x\in X$$ Notice that $T^{-1}$ is also a norm preserving linear bijection.


   In this case we would say that $X$ and $Y$ are *isometrically isomorphic*.
2. There exists a bounded (continuous) linear bijection $T : X \to Y$. As a consequence of the Open Mapping Theorem, $T^{-1}$ is also a bounded liner bijection.
3. There exists a bijective isometry $f : X \to Y$, i.e. norm preserving but not necessarily linear. $f^{-1}$ is also isometric. As a consequence of the Mazur-Ulam Theorem, the map $f$ is necessarily affine. Thus, if we also have $f(0) = 0$, then $f$ is a linear isometry so we are it the situation $(1)$.

In fact, if $X$ and $Y$ are real spaces then [$(3) \implies (2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81086/144766).

Comment: Thank you! If I understand the clause *isomorphic in the vector and norm sense* is ambigiuous.

Comment: @Carucel Yes, although the most probable intention is that they are isometrically isomorphic, IMO.