# Is a surjective isometry an isomorphism?

Tags: functional-analysis

Isomorphism is defined as a bijective linear operator, while isometry is inherently injective but not necessarily surjective. But if we have a surjective isometry, can we say it must be an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes you can....

Comment: Provided you mean linear isometry when you say isometry. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59374/example-of-a-non-linear-isometry for examples of isometries that aren't linear

Comment: How is this actually proven? Specifically the multiplication preserving aspect of the homomorphism in the case of algebras. Or does the result not extend to algebras?